# How to call the API http://127.0.0.1:9999 in my angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I have an angular application ,and I have called the two API's http://xx.xxx.xxx.338/api/login and
http://xx.xxx.xxx.338/api/jammers and received the data from the server .
But I am unable to call the API http://127.0.0.1:9999 in my angular project
.service function is

**dashboard.service.ts**

```
export class DashboardService {
  public datas: any[];
  public mac:any;
  public ssid:any;
  public signals:any;
  public jammers:any[];
  dta:any;

  url:'http://127.0.0.1:9999';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    mapping(){
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(
        (dronesdt:any)=>{
          localStorage.setItem("dronesdt",JSON.stringify(dronesdt));
          console.log("Drones",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dronesdt")))
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**.component.ts**

```
mapping(){
  this.drones=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dronesdt"));
  console.log("Drones",this.drones)
}
```

I want to receive the data from the API in my angular applicaton.

Comment: Please update your post and explain what you mean by "I am unable to call the API".  Please copy/paste an exact error message, if possible.

Comment: "I am unable to call the API" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cors is not the answer

```
url:'http://127.0.0.1:9999'
```

Will not work the ":" defines the type not the value.

```
url: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:9999'
```